# inserting mp3 file into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am making a project in which i can view and play mp3 files on the site of my own but i am not able to insert mp3 file into database.
how to insert mp3 file into MySQL database(phpmyadmin) in PHP and then fetch that file from the database to display it on the web page.

Comment: What have you tried? I'd recommend storing the file on your server and only store the location in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't store mp3 files in the database - that's what the **filesystem** is for.

You need to upload the file to your server (Be sure to give this specific location permissions).

After you upload the file to your filesystem you'll need to store only the **location** of the file in your mysql database.